# How to protect against thieves unlocking iPhones and stealing money from bank apps?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security, password, accounts

This week some newspaper articles were published in Brazil regarding burglars that are stealing cell phones looking not to resell them or disassemble for parts, but rather to steal money from banking apps. An example is [this one](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2021/06/criminosos-de-sp-agora-roubam-celulares-para-limpar-contas-bancarias-das-vitimas.shtml) (in Portuguese, but perfectly readable using Google Translate.) In a Brazilian Apple forum, there are quite a few first-party reports of this in [this thread](https://forum.macmagazine.com.br/topic/180390-iphone-11-roubado-e-icloud-desbloqueado/).

I've been unable to find any specifics on the methods used by these burglars to unlock the stolen iPhones. It bears mentioning that victims mentioned in the links above confirmed they didn't reveal their passcodes, since otherwise the problem would be much easier.

How likely is it that criminal can get access to apps inside a locked iPhone without knowing the passcode (e.g. by misusing account recovery? And what risk mitigation strategies could be used to protect against these attacks without excessively impacting the phone's usability?

Comment: `the most believable explanation I've found is that they take out the SIM card from the stolen iPhone, insert it into another iPhone, and perform an iCloud password recovery using the recovery phone number` Do you not need the associated AppleID and Password to activate an Apple account on a new phone?

Comment: "Forced toreveal their password"? Really, you mean tortured? I have had several scam emails pretending to be from my bank - each time I have phoned my bank and they say no we have not contacted you since xxxxx and ask me to forward the email to their fraud department.

Comment: @Solar Mike if a burglar asks you for your passcode at gunpoint after taking your phone, I’m fairly sure you’ll oblige, no torture required.

Comment: Sorting your society’s problems is beyond the scope of this Stack.

Comment: I’m just trying to sort out Apple’s gaping security holes. Your opinion on my country is uncalled for and indeed unwelcome. In addition, last I heard, Brazil doesn’t have a monopoly on burglaries.

Comment: This seems to need a major edit to get a positive reception here. Why would it matter where criminals try to game the system? Most of this needs to be put in an answer so the question can be more clear about something practical that’s to be solved Imo. Let’s put a pause on things to clarify how this reads.

Comment: @bmike disagree. There's no point in locking down the phone to the point that it is unusable (e.g. putting all apps under Screen Time with a 1 minute timeout, disabling FaceID, etc.), unless it actually protects against a concrete scenario where a criminal could gain access to it. This is exactly what the question is about: what exactly could these criminals be doing to access the phone without knowing the passcode. Once you know the attack surface, you can effectively protect against it.

Comment: @bmike despite my disagreement, I dramatically trimmed down the question, and will move the rest to an answer, should the question be reopened. Please consider reopening the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I removed the speculative part about possible methods, after all I assume you look for answers about specific protection measures, not about attack speculations.

Comment: @nohillside The section on using the SIM in another phone to get round account recovery seems relevant especially as it makes the answer more relevant

Comment: @mmmmmm The question will lead to rather opion-based answers independent of any phrasing. IMHO we should stick to things which are known.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for techniques I can apply to my phone to mitigate any risk of my bank accounts getting wiped if my phone is stolen.

I'll restrict my answer to this, anything further would in my opinion be speculation.

> Remove FaceID from all banking apps, and use a different password than the iPhone passcode. Even if they somehow figure out the passcode for the iPhone, they can't use that information to access my bank accounts.

That would be my first action. Disable any biometrics and use individual, strong passwords for each of your financial apps.

Not using any financial apps on your device at all would be more secure than using them.

Additionally, you could ensure that any account recovery methods are not using accounts or phone numbers that are attached to your device.

> Unfortunately some "digital wallet" apps (similar to e.g. Paypal) protect transaction with either FaceID or the iPhone passcode

Your options are: log out after use, enable 2 factor authentication (also password protected, and not attached to the phone number of the device), or do not use these apps.

Comment: How does removing FaceId from the financial app solve the issue?

Comment: @mmmmmm it reduces the risk that comes with having biometrics as an access verifier.

Comment: But how does that matter if he phone is lost. The the if does not have the biometrics

Comment: By adding a new face to FaceID, a criminal can access an app that is protected by FaceID even if they don’t know that app’s password, which may be different from the iPhone’s passcode.

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not sure I completely follow your last comment. This is the policy we used in house, and audited for clients during my time in information security. I would highlight that consumer grade biometrics are not comparable to those certified for use in high-security facilities.

Comment: @Scottmeup I missed that your answer depends on thieves having the iPhone passcode which the question now says they do not have

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm not sure that's what I meant, could you highlight the relevant section of my answer that seemed to suggest that for me to review?

Comment: @Scottmeup "Even if they somehow figure out the passcode for the iPhone, they can't use that information to access my bank accounts." and the question said "without knowing the passcode " but now I understand the issues.